# ArrayList looping only outputs the last item

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to loop through an ArrayList, and compare each index value to a default value, if the index value matches the default value, I want to return true, the only problem is that, it always returns true only to the index item that is added. Since my class doesn't have a main method, I have added those values during the class constructor initialization.

```
  public class CountryFinderImpl implements CountryFinder{

    List<String> Countries = new ArrayList<String>();



    public CountryFinderImpl() {

        Countries.add("canada");
        Countries.add("japan");
        Countries.add("usa");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean forWeather(String country) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        country = country.toLowerCase();
        boolean c=false;


                for(int i=0; i<Countries.size();i++) {
                    if(Countries.get(i).equals(country)) {
                        //System.out.println(country+"Weather available");
                        c=true;
                    }else {
                        //System.out.println(country+"weather unavilable");
                        c=false;
                    }

                }


        return c;
    }

}
```

The country parameter is passed from another class, which takes the country value from the user.

Comment: In the loop: `if(Countries.get(i).equals(country)) { return true; }`  *After* the loop, `return false;` -- so if nothing in the loop matches, it defaults to false

Comment: But even when i pass something inside the arraylist it still returns false, it only returns true for the last item in the arraylist

Comment: Loop could be replaced by `return countries.contains(country.toLowerCase());`

Comment: What exactly is this method supposed to do? If you want to return multiple values from it, you have to create a collection and return that.

Comment: your loop doesn't stop when you find the country, you need to break the loop, add break after c= true;

Answer (score 5):

In each iteration of the loop, you overwrite `c`, regardless of its value, so you'll always return the result fot the last element. One solution is to use the "early return" idiom and return `true` immediatly when the item is found:

```
@Override
public boolean forWeather(String country) {
    country = country.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < Countries.size() ;i++) {
         if (Countries.get(i).equals(country)) {
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note, however, that this is just a reimplementation of the `contains` method, so you might as well just use it:

```
@Override
public boolean forWeather(String country) {
     return Countries.contains(country.toLowerCase());
}
```